# PHP Stream Write Buffer

Tags: php, sockets, php-socket

I am trying to write a large amount of data (~250K) to a stream in a non-blocking fashion.

Abstracting away the complexities and object structure, this is what I am running:

```
$fp = fsockopen('host', 80);
socket_set_blocking( $fp, false );
fwrite( $fp, $string, $length ); // Where $string is a 250K string
```

However the data doesn't all get written. Assuming this was PHP's write buffer coming into play, I set `stream_set_write_buffer( $fp, 0 )` but that didn't solve the problem either.

I broke my fwrite into chunks of 4096B - and it looks like the client sends 3 complete batches (of 4096 bytes) and ~1500B of the fourth batch. Any and all successive calls to fwrite return 0 bytes written.

Does anyone have any idea how I can queue this data to all be sent out in a non-blocking fashion? If I remove `socket_set_blocking( $fp, false );` - it all works fine. So clearly it's an issue with running it asynchronously.

What are your thoughts? Would the sockets extension help here at all? Does it handle buffers differently?

Note: I am intentionally writing this socket transport layer to avoid using curl for various reasons. Using `curl_multi()` is not an option.

Comment: You should use `socket_select()` to find out whether the socket is ready for writing.

Comment: Can't use socket_select without recompiling PHP due to file limit issues. The select() system call is relatively poor for this. - Is that my only option?

Comment: What do you mean by file limit issues? How many sockets do you have?

Comment: This is running on a web server that is capable of serving hundreds of websites and tons of requests. We are well beyond the default-limit of 1024 max open files, even though I'm only opening one socket. It's a limitation of the select() system call.

Comment: You have a string that is 1/4 a megabyte? The concation to make that is probably going to hurt your servers performance sometime.

Comment: do you want non blocking so that you can work on multiple separate io operations at once(to save time), or do you want non block so you can continue on executing the rest of the program?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this, per request you have more than 1024 sockets open??

Comment: @rambocoder Once I can solve this for one request, yes. The end goal is that we actually spawn off three socket connections and wait for the first one to respond, then discard the other two. This is for a high-availability web service.

Comment: @Jack No, we don't have more than 1024 sockets open per requests. In a CLI environment, socket_select works fine. However, when run under apache, apache has file descriptors open for each of its child processes, each of the log files we write to, etc, etc. The sum total of ALL of this (which is the total active file descriptor count for the user) is beyond 1024.

Comment: The biggest set of file descriptors you can pass to `socket_select()` is probably 1024, but I don't think that's related to how many file descriptors Apache has opened on its process' behalf. Of course, I could be wrong because I've never ran into this issue before :)

Comment: `socket_select()` and `stream_select()` both check the current number of file descriptors held by the user, and, if greater than FD_SETSIZE (which is 1024 by default) throw a warning. The `select` call also fails in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly due to the fact that `fwrite` operations on non-blocking socket streams can be interrupted by the arrival of new packets. As a result, you can't count on an `fwrite` to be atomic. In such cases you **MUST** rely on the return value of your `fwrite` invocation to tell you exactly how many bytes were written to the stream in that pass and continue writing until all your data is sent.

For example ...

```
$dataToWrite = 'my data';
$bytesToWrite = strlen($dataToWrite);
$totalBytesWritten = 0;

while ($totalBytesWritten < $bytesToWrite) {
    $bytes = fwrite($mySock, substr($dataToWrite, $totalBytesWritten));
    $totalBytesWritten += $bytes;
}
```

Obviously, a robust treatment of this problem must also account for situations where the socket connection goes away, etc.

Comment: Yes but after the first fwrite returns a partial write, ALL subsequent calls to fwrite appear to return 0 - although the socket reports that it's still open.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Then you should be using `stream_select` and only writing when it tells you that the stream can accept a write operation without blocking. You may also need to verify that the socket *really is* still alive. You can do this with `is_resource($stream) && !feof($stream)`

Comment: See my comment above to my own answer just now - stream_select unfortunately doesn't work in our environment. Also, I am positive that the socket connection is available. `is_resource($stream) && !feof($stream)` returns true and by just making the socket synchronous everything works as expected. The connection is not being dropped.

Comment: I may have lied in my first comment. I just realized that I wasn't using the return value of fwrite to decrement my $bytesWritten, I was just subtracting off the total number of bytes I tried to write. I will make these changes tomorrow and be back to comment.

Comment: The comment above mentions `socket_select` specifically and not `stream_select`. Unfortunately if you can't use `stream_select` you have no business working with non-blocking sockets in PHP -- it's an essential function if you want to do anything useful with non-blocking socket streams. A default php install has this enabled, though shared hosting often will not. It sounds like you need to fix your environment before doing anything else ...

Comment: Sure thing. I'm happy to help. If you continue to have major problems feel free to ping me over [in the php chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) -- I'm generally idling there.

Comment: This is a dedicated server (one of our physical machines) but the only way to solve the stream_select issue is to recompile PHP which isn't the best option right now (mostly because we are running on the Zend Server platform from an RPM). Also, both `stream_select` and `socket_select` ultimately defer to the system select call - I checked the PHP source when I ran into this issue yesterday.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Ugh. Sounds terrible. The problem with not having access to `stream_select` is that your non-blocking `fwrite`s are going to be invoked repeatedly whether the socket can handle a write or not. It's going to choke your CPU ... not really a viable option IMHO.

Comment: You were right on this - this method did work. We didn't end up going this route but I still accepted this as the answer.

Comment: I'm jumping in with a comment that probably won't help directly: a somewhat faster version of the code, if it will do any good: `do { $dataToWrite = substr($dataToWrite, fwrite($mySock, $dataToWrite)); } while (!empty($dataToWrite));` This version tosses data once it's written instead of `substr`ing it every time it's necessary. The code could probably do with a `stream_select` call but that's apparently not possible in this situation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accounting for blocking and retries?  I would assume you need to account for EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK/EINTR states otherwise you are going to end up blocking yourself.